# Concatenation of literal strings in C

Tags: c

I am programming a uC. To interact with the uC I've written an menu. In this menu I want to print some information on a PC in a terminal window (in this case tera term VT).
Therefore I want to print something like this:
`dec. duty cycle by x%` and x should be replaced by a number defined in a marco. To do this, each menu item contains a description string. This string is passed to the menu item via the `1interlaceMenuFct(...)`-function an will be printed to the terminal by the `print_text(...)`-function. So I wrote:

Header file:

```
#define X 5
#define _STR(s)  #s
#define _XSTR(s) _STR(s)

extern void interlaceMenuFct(menuFct_t *fct, const char *description, const char *symbol, menuItem_t *parent, menuFct_t *prev, void *action, unsigned char cnt); 
extern void print_text(const char *text);
```

in code file:

```
interlaceMenuFct(&decDC_mf,"dec. duty cycle by "_XSTR(X)"%","-",&io_mi,&incDC_mf,&decrementDutyCycle,0);
```

Here I use the `_XSTR(s)`-function to replace the X by the number.

Now my "problem": This works, but I do not understand why.
The function `interlaceMenuFct(...)` expect a pointer to the string. But in the function call I (think that I) create three strings: `dec. ...`, `5`, `%`
Does it works because these strings are static and the linker place them in ascending order in the memory or does the compiler concatenate this three strings automatically, because there is nothing else written between the "-tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§5.1.1.2 of the C standard describes the various stages of compilation (referred to as "translation" in the document). Specifically, stage six is:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

In other words, after macro expansion takes place (which is stage 4), any string literals right next to each other (aka adjacent) are combined into one large string. Thus, the 3 strings `"dec. duty cycle by "`, `"5"`, and `"%"` are combined into one large string `"dec. duty cycle by 5%"`.

Then, later on in stage 7, the code is actually compiled into machine code, so it sees the `interlaceMenuFct` call with only one string in that parameter.

Comment: @PaulSchäfer It's a "compiler feature" in the sense that if a compiler doesn't support it, then it's not a true C compiler.